# Sorting Issue: YUI3 Datatable with Paginator

Tags: javascript, yui3

I have created YUI3 Datatable with Pagination (used gallery module: gallery-datatable-paginator).

```
    var withColumnLabels = new Y.DataTable({
        columns: columnDef,
        data   : data,
        summary: "Price sheet for inventory parts",
        caption: "These columns have labels and abbrs",
        sortBy: {"mfr_parts_database_name":"desc"},
        paginator: new Y.PaginatorView({
           model:      new Y.PaginatorModel({itemsPerPage:2}),
           container:  '#labelsPaginatorTemplate'
        })

    }).render('#labels');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/MqwyU/5/

In the above URL, sorting is enabled by default in second column. After render data table, If I am going to sort first column, the second column sorting icon not change as default indicator. Please anyone suggest me to fix the same.

It is working fine if I am not use gallery-datatable-paginator.

```
    var withColumnLabels = new Y.DataTable({
        columns: columnDef,
        data   : data,
        summary: "Price sheet for inventory parts",
        caption: "These columns have labels and abbrs",
        sortBy: {"mfr_parts_database_name":"desc"}
    }).render('#labels');
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mail2asik/r3Cbu/6/

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue using "pageUpdate" event but it is not perfect solutions because it should be fixed in core level.

```
    //pageupdate event
    withColumnLabels.on('pageUpdate', function (e) {
        var sortBy = this.get('sortBy');
        if(sortBy){
            Y.all(".yui3-datatable-table thead>tr>th").removeClass('yui3-datatable-sorted').removeClass('yui3-datatable-sorted-desc');    
            var sortObj = sortBy[0],
            sortKey = Y.Object.keys(sortObj)[0],
            key=sortObj[sortKey];           
            if(key=="1"){
                Y.one(".yui3-datatable-table .yui3-datatable-col-"+sortKey).addClass("yui3-datatable-sorted");
            }else{      
                Y.one(".yui3-datatable-table .yui3-datatable-col-"+sortKey).addClass("yui3-datatable-sorted").addClass("yui3-datatable-sorted-desc");
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MqwyU/7/